# Remove dots and spaces from strings

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace

I want to remove dots `.` and spaces   with regex `text.replace(/[ .]+/g, '')`.

> This is an  8-string `12.34.5678`; and this is another 13-string `1234 5678 9123 0` okay?

But the main problem is that it removes all dots and spaces, from the sentence.

> Thisisan8-string12345678;andthisisanother13-string1234567891230okay?

- an 8-string `12.34.5678`
- another 13-string `1234 5678 9123 0`

Needs to be converted to.

- an 8-string `12345678`
- another 13-string `1234567891230`

So the sentence will be:

> This is an 8-string `12345678`; and this is another 13-string `1234567891230` okay?

What am I doing wrong? Im stuck with finding/matching the right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
s.replace(/(\d)[\s.]+(?=\d)/g, '$1')
s.replace(/(?<=\d)[\s.]+(?=\d)/g, '')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V7d90V/1).

**Details**

- `(\d)` - Group 1 (`$1` in the replacement pattern is the value of the group): a digit
- `[\s.]+` - one or more whitespace or `.` chars
- `(?=\d)` - a positive lookahead that ensures the next char is a digit.

See JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = 'This is an 8-string 12.34.5678; and this is another 13-string 1234 5678 9123 0 okay?';
console.log(text.replace(/(\d)[\s.]+(?=\d)/g, '$1'));
```

Comment: Nice one, and thanks for the detailed explanation. But what to do when a word/letter starts immediately after a string/digit like "12.34.5678and this is another1234 5678 9123 0okay?"

Comment: @RRG And what do you expect then?

Comment: I expect it to be like this "12345678 and this is another 1234567891230 okay?" I want a space always, before the first and last digit. So it wont conflict when accidentally a text has a letter connected with a number like /\d+/g https://jsfiddle.net/rrggrr/qmurjtgf/

Comment: @RRG See https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/6tmyg28n/1/

Answer (score 0):

Tested your answer but didn't work with this input 'be0.9 9 99.999.99.'

Could fix it with this line of code: x.replace(/[\s.]+/g, '')